# Pandoc cannot find sty files which are installed using TexLive Vanilla

Tags: ubuntu, pandoc, texlive-2020

I am trying to use pandoc to create a markdown file from a tex file. The conversion fails. One of the error messages is that it cannot find my .sty files that are located

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty

and here

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty

How can I tell pandoc to find my sty files (there are much more than just one)? I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Tex Live 2020.
Thanks a lot!